# centos sftp delete key say wave

Tags: linux, centos, sftp

I'm working on CentOS.

I frequently use sftp for transfer files.

But after I connect to sftp 'delete' key does not work.

When I press 'Delete' only '~' typed.

On the ssh command delete key works but only in sftp does not work and print '~'.

How du I have to figure out this..?(I want to use delete key)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's a normal behaviour.

OpenSSH `sftp` does not implement full line editing capabilities.

Comment: Not sure. In my Debian I have `sftp` from `openssh-client` package (version `1:7.4p1-10+deb9u6`). I can edit lines, delete *does* work. Tested by connecting from Windows to my Debian via PuTTY with local line editing forced off, keypad sequences setting: "Linux"; then connecting with `sftp` to yet another host. The sequence "Ctrl+v delete" prints `^[[3~`. (Note: after I change "Linux" to "VT400", delete prints `~` in `sftp` (it's actually `^[[4~`) but it stops working as delete in the shell). Can `sftp` in Debian be so much modified? Or did I test it wrong? Or is your belief wrong?

Comment: I do not know. Anyway, even with your non-default settings, it does not work for me (even though the Delete works in the shell).